# Can anyone help me solve the error in this SQL function

Tags: mysql, sql-function

I am trying to create a function which will return the name of the day one is born.I am passing the name of person as parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION name_of_day (name_of_student VARCHAR(150))
RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DAYNAME(`date_of_birth`) AS 'Name of week' 
            FROM student 
            WHERE student.student_name = name_of_student);
END;
```

I got the error message

> Error Code : 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "AS" from it, on line three, see if that works :) good luck!

Here's a basic example from mysqltutorial.org:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION CustomerLevel(
    credit DECIMAL(10,2)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE customerLevel VARCHAR(20);

IF credit > 50000 THEN
    SET customerLevel = 'PLATINUM';
ELSEIF (credit >= 50000 AND 
        credit <= 10000) THEN
    SET customerLevel = 'GOLD';
ELSEIF credit < 10000 THEN
    SET customerLevel = 'SILVER';
END IF;
-- return the customer level
RETURN (customerLevel);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: it doesnt work Query : CREATE FUNCTION name_of_day (name_of_student VARCHAR(150))  RETURNS VARCHAR(150)  BEGIN  RETURN(SELECT DAYNAME(`date_of_birth`)A...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Which version are you running? I pulled your code over into my own instance, and it passed. I also removed the alias from the select, same as the other poster. Is there anything else being executed in a larger query, along with this?

Comment: my version is 5.5.45